# which class/jar file in fisheye hooks into subversion and GIT?

Tags: java, atlassian-fisheye

which class/jar file in fisheye hooks into subversion and GIT?

I want to use it to extend the functionality a bit.

Answer (score 1):

For Subversion, FishEye can either use [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/) (the pure-Java Subversion client) or JavaHL (the native bindings shipped with Subversion).  These aren't specific to FishEye.  See the `lib/svn` in your FishEye distribution for all the bits.

For Git, the documentation suggests that it just calls the Git command-line utilities and parses the results (which would be why they need to be in your `PATH` when starting up FishEye).  I strongly suspect this functionality is built into FishEye itself and not part of a bundled library.

Answer (score 0):

Well, [FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/) being a closed source product, I don't think the internal API and core classes are publicly documented. So, except if you are writing a [plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/search/by/fisheye), I would rather send this question to the support. I'm not sure they will give you the required details though. In this case, you should open a Jira issue to get the desired behavior implemented in the product.

Comment: Certainly wasn't me.  I just upvoted your answer since after re-reading the question I'm really not sure what he's after.

Comment: @ZoogieZork Even if it was you, that wouldn't be a problem, downvoting is part of the system and makes it reliable. But a comment is always appreciated (e.g to get a chance to fix an answer or to understand why it's wrong) and, in this particular case, I don't see what's wrong with my answer. Very frustrating.